# MongoDB sort by field with translations

Tags: mongodb, sorting, multilingual, collation

I'm working with documents that have the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b28d08cd7a04b02b31d4543"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2018-06-19T09:44:44.957Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-06-19T09:44:44.957Z"),
"created_by" : ObjectId("5b051b6ff4f98d1681835615"),
"title" : [ 
    {
        "lang" : "es",
        "name" : "Hola",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b28d08cd7a04b02b31d4544")
    },
    {
        "lang" : "en",
        "name" : "Hello",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b28d08cd7a04b02b31d4545")
    }
],
"admins" : [],
"active" : true,
"__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to sort the documents by the title property, but as you can see the title is not a text property so I added the following index:

```
TopicSchema.index(
  { 'title.name': 'text' },
  {
    collation: {
      locale:   'en',
      strength: 1,
     },
     language_override: 'lang',
   }
)
```

My issue is that when I query the documents sorted by `title` I get the documents in some weird order. I don't know if I can specify the 'lang' in which I want to sort or it just picks the first(?) element.

It seemed to me that the documents were sorted because I got all the documents with capital letters at the beginning (so I added the 'collation' option to the index schema), but when I checked carefully and noticed the lowercase elements are not really sorted.

I get confused about how the sorting will work if the document has 3 languages, which language will it use for sorting?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. What I did was creating extra fields of the form:
`title_s: { en: 'Hello', es: 'Hola' }` and keep them in sync through a hook. Not elegant at all, but it works. These fields are just used for sorting.